# Send mass texts with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sms

Is there anyway to send the same text to multiple contacts not as a group text. I have been told that it would need a server to accomplish this. If that is the case I would like to be able to still send texts from my current number not a new number. I have checked out Twilio but have not gotten very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot send mass text messages using Twilio and your existing phone number.

One option you might have is, if you have a Mac you can control the SMS app programmatically to send lots of SMS messages. Here's a blog post with some example code to do that: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/drawing-pixel-art-text-messages-signal-video-wall.html

That might not be of much help, but while you can send lots of SMS messages with Twilio, you cannot do so using your existing number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could send mass texts out to different numbers using twilio. No you could not use your current number. 
You would have to purchase a new twilio number that has SMS messaging enabled. 
Look at the Twilio documentation and their get started guide, figure out the language you want to create your server in and you will be sending texts in no time. https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/node/programmable-sms You would run the webserver. Twilio does not offer a swift or ios based SMS solution.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart?filter-language=swift